# SQL Server : how to order by using a starting value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query to order a table by a value starting at a certain value.

**Current:**

```
ZQE123
ABC123
ABC324
ALP234
```

If I order by from variable 'ABC324'

```
ABC324
ALP234
ZQE123
ABC123
```

If I order by from variable 'ZZZ123'

```
ABC123
ABC324
ALP234
ZQE123
```

It's basically a ordered circular list depending on which variable is specified.

I've tried using the `RANK()` function, but haven't had too much luck.

```
SELECT 
    Location, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Location) 
FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
ZQE123    4 
ABC123    1
ABC324    2 
ALP234    3
```

How can I get it to do it based on the current location?

Comment: What is the desired order of these items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN YourCol >= @Variable THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END,
          YourCol
```

Would be one way. Or another (assumes no nulls)

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Part,
                *
         FROM   T
         WHERE  YourCol >= @Variable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS Part,
                *
         FROM   T
         WHERE  YourCol < @Variable)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE
ORDER  BY Part,
          YourCol
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option, though I like **Martin Smith**'s answer:

```
DECLARE @Start CHAR(6) = 'ABC324';

DECLARE @T TABLE (Val CHAR(6));
INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('ZQE123'), ('ABC123'), ('ABC324'), ('ALP234');

DECLARE @Count INT;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM @T;


;WITH Ranked AS
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Val) Ord FROM @T
)
SELECT Val FROM Ranked
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Val >= @Start THEN Ord ELSE Ord + @Count END;
```